# What does これくらい mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, manga

Dialogue goes as follows:

> A: へー！アンタってお嬢さんだからピザ切れないと思ってた。
>
> B: これくらい...!バカにしないでよね！

I understand they're saying "Don't be stupid" But can't figure out what the これくらい is supposed to be doing there.

Comment: I think it's simply just これ + くらい, meaning something like "That's about it." Did they show a picture of her cutting the pizza?

Comment: @Nameless Yes they did! So it mean's "that's about it?"

Comment: Manab's translation is much better: "This much!" Just keep in mind it's これ + くらい, where くらい is a particle meaning "approximately" and これ represents the amount of pizza that was cut.

Comment: This is why context is important. これ is just a demonstrative pronoun.

Comment: It is meant for something along the lines of これくらいできるわよ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This これ ("this") refers to the action in question, namely the **pizza-cutting**. くらい is used to indicate the marked noun (これ) is not difficult/important/etc.

And ばかにする is not "to be stupid" but "to mock someone" or "to make a fool of someone".

> これくらい...! バカにしないでよね！
>
> This is just a...! Don't make a fool of me!
> <sup>("This" = "Pizza-cutting")</sup>
>
> Something like this is...(easy even to me)! Don't make fun of me!

Comment: +1 but note that "to fool" and "to mock" are not synonyms (at least in modern usage). "to fool" means "to deceive" whereas "to mock" means "to make fun of" as you used in your last translation. You could also use "to **make** a fool of" instead of "to mock".

Comment: @user3856370 Thank you, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much context, but maybe it means something like "don't be "this much" of an idiot. Or maybe it's just referring to the pizza.

Comment: That's what I thought initially but then saw that the これくらい is separated from the バカ part so I thought that maybe it wasn't actually modifying this second part of the sentence. So more likely it refers to the pizza like you said. But what would it mean if that's the case?

Comment: To me, it sounds like: "what?  I thought a woman like you could not cut a pizza!" "She takes a big piece of it" "This much! You're making me sound like a fool/don't make me look like a fool!". I adapted a little, but that's how it sounds to me.